# How to make Django HTML IF statement to include all child paths of current url

Tags: html, django

I can use django html logic (not sure what it is called) to post something on the page if the url is exactly something (see below). How do I get the if statement to be true for all child pages. E.g. if the path is '/chat/', then '/chat/1/1', '/chat/members', etc. Is it possible to use the name space somehow?

HTML

```
{% if request.get_full_path in "/chat/" %}
      <p>found it</p>
{% endif %}
```

URL Namespace

```
url(r'^chat/', include("chat.urls",namespace='chat')),
```

App URL Namespace

```
url(r'^$', chat_view, name='chats'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this!

```
  {% url 'chat:chats' as first_url %}
  {% if first_url not in request.path%}
      <p>You are not in the chats namespace</p>
  {% endif %}
```